# Why do I see cgi source code on my webserver instead of its output?

Tags: apache2, php, browser, webserver, cgi

***In case 1, I cannot see the cgi script executed output in browser and see source code instead.
However, in case 2, with similar configuration i can see the cgi script executed output in browser.***

**Case 1:**
Ubuntu Version : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Apache Version : Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
                 Server built:   Apr  3 2014 12:20:28

PHP Version    : PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 16:36:58) 
                 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
                 Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
                 with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by
                 Zend Technologies

I dont not have httpd installed on this machine. Hence, no httpd.conf

**Case 2:**
I have a similar machine configuration where the cgi-script works perfectly fine: 
Ubuntu Version : Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Apache Version : Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
                 Server built:   Jul 24 2015 17:25:11
PHP Version    : PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 11:44:57) 
                 Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
                 Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
                 with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by 
                 Zend Technologies

Here, cgi script works as expected. Even though no httpd.

Please let me know what am I missing and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you grep `http` process? no httpd.conf does not mean httpd is not running.

Comment: also do `netstat -ntulp | grep 80` and share the output.

Comment: Case 1: tcp6       0      0 :::8085                 :::*                    LISTEN      1249/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1131/jsvc.exec  
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1249/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      1249/apache2    
udp6       0      0 fe80::250:56ff:fe93:123 :::*                                1443/ntpd

Comment: Case 2: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1480/postgres   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2049/apache2

Comment: there is apache(httpd) running on port 80. your httpd is not configured correctly on the directory where you only see CGI as the source code, hence the CGI is not being executed.

Comment: What could be the configuration difference in the two systems? Please let me know what is the correct configuration.

Comment: do you know how to configure CGI in httpd? This will help. [CGI Guide](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/simple-cgi-and-apache-examples-on-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Didnt need to make any configuration changes.

Following commands worked for me:

sudo a2enmod cgi

sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: that the problem you did not activate CGI module. actually you made the configuration change by running `a2enmod`.